# Insert values from a file in a latex document

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, latex, pdflatex

If a have a latex document, how can I read some key-value pairs from a file an insert them into the document?

Something like this:

Latex code:

```
customer ID: ${customerID}
```

Text file:

```
customerID=123456
```

And the resulting `.pdf` file should contain the customer ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can always write a perl script to expand them...

defs.txt:

```
 customerID=123456
 customerTel=22530000000
```

doc.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
latex
customer ID: ${customerID}
and ${address} 
costum telphone ID: ${customerTel}
\end{document}
```

perl script tex-defs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

BEGIN{$tex=0;}

if(not $tex and /^(\w+)=(.*)/) { $v{$1}=$2 }
if(/\\documentclass\{/       ) { $tex=1  }
if($tex)                       { s/\$\{(\w+)\}/$v{$1} || "???$1"/ge; print }
```

testing (after chmod...):

```
$ tex-defs defs.txt doc.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
latex
customer ID: 123456
and ???address
costum telphone ID: 22530000000
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just import a .dat file using the following code in your preamble:

```latex
% package to open file containing variables
\usepackage{datatool, filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{,}% Set the separator between the columns.

% import data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{../mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
```

Please notice that in this example `keys` and `values` are separated using a comma. My .dat file looks like the following:

```
number_participants,21
total_score,32.55
```

Then in the body of your LaTeX document just reference the variable using this command: `\var{variable_name}`

For more information watch [this video](https://youtu.be/LufMPezEN6Y).

Answer (score 3):

If you have some data (for instance your customerID) in a file that is saved to say 'data/foo.dat', then you could use that value in your .tex-file like this:

```
This is the customerID: \input{data/foo.dat}.
```

Then the pdf would show

```
This is the customerID: 123456.
```

The command **\input** just inserts whatever is inside the file you provide. I'm not quite sure about how to get the key-value pairs working, but maybe you could make it so that the values you need are stored in files with the "key" as the filename. If you place these files in some subfolder it would not clutter your working directory, and may be just as good a place as any to store your data.