# How to Insert text elements from a dataframe variable into knitr/LaTeX document?

Tags: r, text, latex, markdown, knitr

Using `knitr` and `LaTeX`, I would like to insert specified text from an R object (ideally a data frame) at various locations in the PDF output.  [The text consists of scores of blog posts currently in a .csv file which is easily read into R as a data frame.]

Here is one method that only partially works because I don't know how to specify a particular piece of the .txt file.  With youressay.txt in the working directory [two lines: "Can I import into Latex? Or is it difficult?"], the `LaTeX` code below in my .Rnw script inputs it nicely, but how can I pick only one of the lines?  [The lines between begin{document} and end{document} come from [input an entire .txt file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/how-do-i-import-a-text-file-so-that-it-becomes-the-body-text-of-my-latex-documen)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.8in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\obeylines
\input{youressay.txt}%
\endgroup%

\end{document}
```

A second method enables control over what element of the character variable in a data frame to insert, but it formats the output unattractively.

```
<<dataset, cache = TRUE, echo = FALSE, include = TRUE>>=
text <- data.frame(post = c("These is the first bit of text.", "This is a second bit of text."))
cat(paste(text$post[2], sep = "\n"))
# Formatted with a hashtag at the start and grey background color  
@
```

Finally, perhaps the method of [insert data in `LaTeX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078107/insert-values-from-a-file-in-a-latex-document) would accomplish what I seek, if it lets me pick portions of the .dat file.

**Can anyone suggest a method along the lines of this imagined code to insert, for example, the fifth element of a data frame's character variable?**

```
\begingroup
\obeylines
\input{dataframe$charactervar[5]}%
\endgroup%
```

Comment: so what's wrong with `\`r dataframe$charactervar[5]\`` ?

Comment: That is Markdown.  I am using LaTeX.

Comment: And the RNW equivalent `\Sexpr{dataframe$charactervar[5]`? Or: set `results="asis"` in the `dataset` chunk.